# Most suitable text for "Saved Queries" for non-tech users

Tags: terminology, text

My website has an option to search and drill down people by various data points. To enable them to save these filters for future use, there is an option to save the filter criteria.

I don't want to call it saved search or saved filters. Currently I am using "Saved Queries" and I feel query may not be the most friendly word given that the users are mostly non-tech savvy. What's the best alternative?

Comment: why don't you want "saved search" or "saved filters" if that's what it _is_?

Comment: Hi MOller, typically user knows/feels he is searching when there is a search box. But here, he is filtering through UI. SO I did not want to call it Search (although actually that is what it is).

Comment: eBay uses 'Saved Search' and that includes saving any applied filters too. You may well find that the users don't really differentiate between 'Search' and 'Filter' anyway.

Comment: -1 Why don't you want to call them saved filters?

Comment: Can you expand your question to explain why you've decided the two obvious options aren't right for your users?

Comment: How do you identify the filters in the save option? Do you say something like "save this search for future use"? The option for using the saved preferences should reflect the language you exposed previously. Eg. "save these search options" -> "apply search options (followed by a drop-down/selector)".

Comment: +1 for your second thought on that! "Filter" or "query" is a function for the user to start an action on a system and change its state (of appearance in this case). The **alteration** of that function is what **has to be saved** and not the filter/query its self.

Comment: Thanks all. I think I could also use the tool tip to clearly say save filter criteria or save search criteria. I have a reset button and it has a tool tip to explain reset all active filters, and I can have a tool tip in a similar way for saving active filters. That should make it clear to the users. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I think a 'Saved Query' or 'Saved Search' implies that keywords or search terms are being saved.  That said maybe 'Bookmarked Searches' is more accessible?

For saving filters I think you could try 'Custom Filters' or 'My Filters'.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your problem: "Saving filters" is in deed an awquard term since others can still use the filters as well after you have "saved" them. They haven't changed ones property or so. Abstract thought, but abstract enough to think about it. You need to extend your term with something more grippy. How about **"save filter *combination*"** or **"save search *criterias*"**?

Edit: Btw. Evernotes english version uses the term "saved searches" whereas the german version titles this with "saved search procedures" ("Gespeicherte Suchvorgänge")

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the context something like *My selections* / *Saved selections* / *Previous selections* might work.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what the site does you could still use "**Saved search**" or do as Apple Mail – call it "**Save as Smart folder**" and let the user name the filter result for an easy access.